# replacing default attributes in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I would like to be able to change some of the default attributes which are applied to the html. For example when the text alignment is set to right, left, center. The attribute goes like so:

```
<p style="text-align:right">some text</p>
```

I would like it to be

```
<p align="right">some text</p>
```

Does anyone know how this can be done.
Thanks.

Comment: You would like to do this even though it is deprecated?

Comment: Yes, as it would be used outside of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do programmatically on the server side after the user hits submit.

I understand some specs have the shittiest requirements but I do not suggest going into the CKEditor code and changing stuff there. It will make it harder to upgrade also.

Comment: Thanks, I think that might be the safest solution. Being a wysiwyg editor it may work with that tag for now but upgrading to a newer browser may remove the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I find out a solution to assign classes to p element rather than style attribute.

```
config.justifyClasses = [ 'AlignLeft', 'AlignCenter', 'AlignRight', 'AlignJustify' ];
```

Then you should add these classes in your css file. Works fine for me.